Шифрование поступающих данных sql server
В качестве обучения мне нужно создать базу данных + форму регистрации на Python, откуда в БД будут заноситься данные пользователя (его логин, пароль и дата_время входа). Мне нужно зашифровать столбец с паролями. Пароли которые уже занесены в базу - шифруются, а новые, которые вводит пользователь нет. Python выдаёт ошибку.
Подскажите пожалуста алгоритм, как сделать, чтобы когда пользователь вводит пароль в базу данных он заносился уже в зашифрованном виде.

В какой точке будет выполняться шифрование - на стороне python перед отправкой на сервер или на стороне SQL Server после получения незашифрованного пароля?

После получения незашифрованного пароля, со стороны SQL server

Ну тогда показывайте тот запрос, который должен, по вашему мнению. зашифровать переданный пароль.

У меня его нет, и я не знаю, возможно ли это. Поэтому уточняю здесь. Мне нужно понять, каким способом можно зашифровать пароль, после того, как его ввёл пользователь.

def click():
login = login_input.get()
password = password_input.get()
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = 'INSERT INTO Users  VALUES (?,?)'
values = (login, password)
cursor.execute(query, values)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()  #Функция для передачи пароля и логина в базу

Во-первых, добавляйте факты в текст вопроса (можно пометить как апдейт), и с нормальным форматированием. Во-вторых, где в показанном коже ну хоть что-то, похожее на шифрование?
